# Delete_from and delete

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a customised table which has a prodid reference in it which refers the prodtable.

I need to delete the Prod table record from this customsied table record . 
but when i access the Prod table and try to delete it,the control just comes out without performing the operation

i have tried using

```
    delete_from ProdTable where prodTable.prodid == 'abc';
```

also

```
    select prodtable where prodTable.prodid =='abc';
    prodTable.delete();
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening

Regards,
TJ

Comment: What version of AX are you using?

Answer (score 4):

First of all I would check if the `select` is returning the desired record:

```
    select prodtable where prodtable .prodid =='abc';
    info(strFmt('ProdId: %1, RecId: %2', prodtable.ProdId, prodtable .RecId));
```

Note: you need a select for update and be in a transaction to be able to delete (should generate an error if not in a transaction or not using `forupdate`)

```
    ttsbegin;
    select forupdate prodtable where prodtable .prodid =='abc';
    info(strFmt('ProdId: %1, RecId: %2', prodtable.ProdId, prodtable .RecId));
    prodtable.delete();
    ttscommit;
```

*(assuming that `prodtable` is the customized table)*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did not use 'abc' but joined using a field from your customized table.

Maybe the `ProdId` in the customized table is left adjusted but the field in `ProdTable` is right adjusted?

Also have you checked if `prodTable.doDelete` is called in class method `ProdTableType.delete`?

Answer (score 0):

> the control just comes out without performing the operation

Do you need to [refresh the form](http://kashperuk.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/tutorial-reread-refresh-research.html) after calling the delete method?